# How to setup frontend framework over flask backend?

Tags: angular, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I want to develop a small web app for working with data (mainly showing lists of records, editing, adding new ones...). I'm using flask as my backend framework and trying to learn some frontend frameworks (bootstrap, angular and react). I can't figure out how to use them together.

my test project looks like  this

```
flaskr
│   app.py
│
├───static
├───templates
│       index.html
```

it's a blank 'hello world' flask app.
I can't figure out how to implement any of the frontend frameworks within my app. should I put the js libraries in the static dir and use urlof to reference them in  tags?
it seems like a bad method to do so.
I will be glad for some examples or explanations for even one of them. I'm new to web development so anyway I will have to learn something new.

Thank's!

EDIT:
I've decided to work with bootstrap at last. can someone show a more detailed explanation for integrating flask backend with bootstrap frontend?

Comment: They communicate via API endpoints

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to run a REST API with Flask:

You can probably serve your Angular application through Flask. But: I'd try to separate both projects. Usually, in your production environment, you have some sort of server in front of your application. Often this is a ngnix or apache2 web server. Serve the Angular client here and add a reverse proxy at /api that redirects to your Flask backend. During development, you can use the Angular proxy feature to redirect your API calls to e.g. localhost:3000. So, you'll be running Angular with ng serve during development and serve the dist folder on production.

Proxy Config for Angular will look like this (for dev):

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can hit your API via localhost:4200/api/...